# x-editable form with typeahead

Tags: angularjs, typeahead

Hello i am fairly new with X-editable for Angular. I was trying to implement a typeahead or autocomplete box inside an editable form. How do i accomplish it?

here is the code that i have.

```
  <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="equipment in equipments | filter:filterEquipment">
                                    <td width="auto"><span editable-select="equipment.VendorID" e-ng-="selectedVendor" e-form="tableform" e-ng-change="GetItems($data)" e-ng-options="s.ID as s.Name for s in VendorsList">{{showVendors(equipment)}}</span></td>
                                    <td><span editable-text="equipment.ItemID" e-form="tableform" e-typeahead="s.ItemID as s.Name for s in ItemsList">{{showItems(equipment)}}</span></td>
                                    <td><span editable-text="equipment.quantity" e-form="tableform"> {{ equipment.quantity|| 'empty' }}</span></td>
                                    <td><span editable-text="equipment.Cost" e-form="tableform"> {{ equipment.Cost || 'empty' }}</span></td>
                                    <td><span editable-text="equipment.SerialNumber" e-form="tableform"> {{ equipment.SerialNumber || 'empty' }}</span></td>
                                    <td><span editable-text="equipment.Status" e-form="tableform"> {{ equipment.Status || 'empty' }}</span></td>
                                    <td ng-hide="" style="width:20px;"><button type="button" ng-click="deleteEquipment(equipment.id)" class="btn btn-danger pull-right">Delete</button></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
```

i want Typeahead on the second `<td>`

Answer (score 0):

```
<td><span id="itemID" editable-text="equipment.ItemID" e-form="tableform" e-typeahead="s.ItemID as s.Name for s in ItemsList">{{showItems(equipment)}}</span></td>

> //turn to inline mode
> 
> $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';
```

Apply editable() method to these elements

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#itemID').editable();
});
```